# Trying to add javax.xml.soap to RCP when upgrading to Java 11

Tags: eclipse, soap, eclipse-rcp, java-11, target-platform

I want to prepare my RCP app for Java 11. As the app makes SOAP calls, I need to provide the `javax.xml.soap` packages in my build. What is the best way to do this?

All calls are done inside one plugin so I did wonder whether to just fetch the jars I need and put them inside that plugin. But wouldn't it be better add these items to the target definition and make it part of the platform?

After some searching I found `MOXy` the `EclipseLink` project which seems to be what I need. I tried to add this to my target definition but got errors:

```
${eclipse_home} 1212 plug-ins available
https://download.eclipse.org/rt/eclipselink/updates/
Problems occurred while resolving the target contents
    Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
        Cannot satisfy dependency:
            From: EclipseLink MOXy 2.7.7.v20200504-69f2c2b80d (org.eclipse.persistence.moxy.feature.group 2.7.7.v20200504-69f2c2b80d)
            To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; com.sun.mail.jakarta.mail [1.6.4,1.6.4]
        Missing requirement: Jakarta Mail API 1.6.4 (com.sun.mail.jakarta.mail 1.6.4) requires 'java.package; javax.crypto 0.0.0' but it could not be found
        Software being installed: EclipseLink MOXy 2.7.7.v20200504-69f2c2b80d (org.eclipse.persistence.moxy.feature.group 2.7.7.v20200504-69f2c2b80d)
```

I am a bit confused as I thought these install-projects pull in dependencies as required. Is that wrong? How do I fix these errors?

Comment: `javax.crypto` (of any version) is missing in your target platform (maybe it's in a referenced p2 repository, but the target definition file might be limited to some install units only: `<unit id="..." version="..."/>`), so pulling it in fails.

Comment: [Eclipse Orbit](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.orbit) provides lots of plug-ins for various packages including javax.xml.soap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add javax.xml.soap from an Eclipse repository. For example insert this into your target definition between the   tags

```
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="javax.xml.soap" version="1.2.0.v201005080501"/>
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-12"/>
</location>
```

Here https://download.eclipse.org/oomph/archive/reports/download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-12/index.html you can explore the repository, on the bottom expand the Installable Units, and there is a filter. If you need anything else from this repository, you only need a new line with unit id and version.
If javax.xml.soap depends on some other installable unit, you should be able to find it in this repository.